# helmfile: Put Go Template into environmental values

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates, helmfile

I have a particular need. I'd like to add a go template to the environment values, but have them interpreted in releases.values.

Here's a simplified example:

helmfile.yaml

```yaml
releases:
  - name: cluster
    chart: ../charts/cluster
    values:
      - values/cluster/values.yaml.gotmpl

environments:
  development:
    values:
      - ./environments/development/values.yaml.gotmpl
```

values/cluster/values.yaml.gotmpl

```yaml
registry:
  docker:
    url: '{{ .Values | get "registry.docker.url" "" }}'

service-1:
  enabled: {{ .Values | get "service-1.enabled" false }}
  chartValues:
{{ toYaml .Values.service-1.chartValues | indent 4 }}

service-2:
  enabled: {{ .Values | get "service-2.enabled" false }}
  chartValues:
{{ toYaml .Values.service-2.chartValues | indent 4 }}
```

environments/development/values.yaml.gotmpl

```yaml
registry:
  docker:
    url: "registry.hub.docker.com"

service-1:
  enabled: true
  chartValues: 
    image:
      repository: {{ .Values | getOrNil "registry.docker.url" }}/service-1


service-2:
  enabled: true
  chartValues: 
    image:
      repository: {{ .Values | getOrNil "registry.docker.url" }}/service-2
```

In reality there are many services with different `chartValues` for each service.

The problem with this example is that it interprets `registry.docker.url` too early (the values are null at the environment level). I'd like them to be dynamically filled when they arrive at `releases.values`. I think I need to use `tpl` but I haven't succeeded.

thanks for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move **releases** and **environments** to separate files and include them in **helmfile.yaml** with **bases** keyword and yaml doc separator like this:

### helmfile.yaml

```
bases:
  - environments.yaml
---
bases:
  - releases.yaml
```

That should do the work, just be assure to [not use hyphens in values key names (or use index method)](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2192)

I personally use such approach in my deploy repos ([example](https://github.com/zam-zam/helmfile-examples/blob/master/helmfile.yaml))

[Official doc link](https://github.com/helmfile/helmfile/blob/main/docs/writing-helmfile.md#layering-state-files)

Comment: thank you very much for the example github, it's brilliant!